# Applying loop for changing columns name and split text through python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Input File:[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knuce.png)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Desktop/Replace.xlsx",header=None)
df.shape[1]
df['Ind 0'] = df['Col 0'].str[1:]
df['Ind 1'] = df['Col 1'].str[1:]
df['Ind 2'] = df['Col 2'].str[1:]
df.to_excel("C:/Users/Desktop/Replace.xlsx", index=False)
```

Required Output :[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmWXx.png)

I am getting this output from the above code. But, I need for loop for this task (Assign new column name and some slicing operation on column value). So that whenever the number of columns value changes. It will automatically take care and provide the required output as mentioned.

Comment: `df = df.replace('[0-9]', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {'Col 1': ['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D'], 'Col 2': ['2A', '2B', '2C', '2D'], 'Col 3': ['3A', '3B', '3C', '3D']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.replace(regex=r'[0-9]', value= '')
df.columns = ['Ind 1', 'Ind 2', 'Ind 3']
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Ind 1 Ind 2 Ind 3
0     A     A     A
1     B     B     B
2     C     C     C
3     D     D     D
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution.

```
for _ in range(1,df.shape[1]):
    df['Ind ' + str(_)] = df['Col ' + str(_)].str[1:]
```

Does this work? I am not sure if you are starting your Columns with 0 or 1. The input file has Col 0 and your code doesn't. Also, this appends new columns and doesn't replace them the way you have shown in output file.